# PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO DE UPDATE ACTUALIZA TODOS LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA MYSQL, SIN IMPORTAR EL ID

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado, a la hora de ejecutarlo, especifico el Id (Por cierto mi Id es PRIMARY KEY y AUTOINCREMENT) que quiero actualizar y se ejecuta correctamente, cuando reviso la tabla, todos los registros se han actualizado.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `calificaciones`.`SP_UPDATE_REGISTROS` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `calificaciones`.`SP_UPDATE_REGISTROS`
(IN ID INT(11),
IN CAL LONGTEXT,
IN UNI LONGTEXT,
IN NC VARCHAR(10),
IN MAT LONGTEXT,
IN TER LONGTEXT,
IN PER INT(11),
IN COM TEXT,
IN CIC INT(11))
BEGIN
UPDATE calif_prueba SET
Calificacion=CAL,Unidad=UNI,N_Control=NC,
Materia=MAT,Termino=TER,Periodo=PER,Comentario=COM,año=CIC
WHERE Id=ID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te los actualiza todos es porque la condición del WHERE es siempre verdadera; prueba con:

```
WHERE calif_prueba.Id=ID;
```

También puedes cambiar el nombre ID a IdItem por ejemplo y quedaría:

```
WHERE Id=IdItem;
```

El tema está en que en ningún caso uses el mismo nombre. Actualizado sería así:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `calificaciones`.`SP_UPDATE_REGISTROS` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `calificaciones`.`SP_UPDATE_REGISTROS`
(IN IdItem INT(11),
IN CAL LONGTEXT,
IN UNI LONGTEXT,
IN NC VARCHAR(10),
IN MAT LONGTEXT,
IN TER LONGTEXT,
IN PER INT(11),
IN COM TEXT,
IN CIC INT(11))
BEGIN
   UPDATE calif_prueba SET
      Calificacion=CAL,Unidad=UNI,N_Control=NC,
      Materia=MAT,Termino=TER,Periodo=PER,Comentario=COM,año=CIC
WHERE Id=IdItem;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso lo resolvió, por tanto en mi procedimiento almacenado para eliminar el resultado hubiese sido la eliminación de todos los registros, con esto se evitó. Reitero gracias!